# How can I trigger an event when this span value changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-finance

I'm trying to get a console log when the price of the current page's stock changes.

**page:**
https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOG&ei=yvbRVbHSCcKgmAGyu7CoDA

**Element ID:**
#price-panel > div > span > span

**Attempt 1:** *fail*

```
$("#price-panel div span span").onchange = function() { console.log('change')}
```

**Attempt 2:** *fail*

```
document.getElementById('price-panel').children[0].children[0].onchange = function() { console.log('change')}
```

builtwith.com says the javascript is the "google api" which is ambiguous to google searches so that didn't help much.

What event can I watch to find out when this element is change?

Comment: `span` elements don't have an `onchange` event... You could use an interval and compare every minute.

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for something like [Detect changes in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Dom Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events) as your try to listen to text changes in `<span>` you may be able to use [DOMCharacterDataModified](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php).

Or you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) to capture the changes.

```js
var span = document.querySelector('#test');
var text = document.createTextNode('tttt');

// This may be deprecated.
span.addEventListener('DOMCharacterDataModified', function() {
    alert('span text changed to: ' + this.innerHTML);
});

// You may use MutationObserver instead.
var mutateObserver = new MutationObserver(function(records) {
  console.log(records);
});
mutateObserver.observe(span, {
  childList: true,                                 // capture child add/remove on target element.
  characterData: true,                     // capture text changes on target element
  subtree: true,                                   // capture childs changes too
  characterDataOldValue: true  // keep of prev value
});

setTimeout(function() {
  span.innerHTML ='SSSS';
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  span.appendChild(text);
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
  text.data = '3123';
}, 4000);
```

```html
<span id="test">This is a span</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

`span` elements do not have an `onchange` event. One thing you can do is introduce a loop to periodically check the current content with previously held content and do something if the two are different:

```
var content = null,
    $element = $("#price-panel div span span");

setInterval(function() {
    var currentText = $element.text();

    if (currentText != content) {
        // A change has happened
        console.log("Change");
        content = currentText;
    }
}, 30000 /* check every 30 seconds */);
```