# Span value change Event Listener

Tags: javascript

```
<span data-bn-type="text" class="herewego" style="display: none;">25</span>
```

How to set "value change" event for this `span`?

I tried something like this :

```
document.querySelector('.herewego').addEventListener('change', function(){
    alert("Works!");
})
```

So.. nothing happened. What im doing wrong?

Comment: Check this question

Comment: Your question answer was answered in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054115/how-can-i-trigger-an-event-when-this-span-value-changes

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you might need to change the query selector for getElementsByClassName and maybe add a click event idk how you would be able to change the span since its not like an input also where it says display:none well that would hide your text so you cant even see it so remove that

```
document.getElementsByClassName('herewego')[0].addEventListener('click',function(){
alert("Works!");
})
```